# Live Power BI Dataset to Azure SQL Database possibility?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are getting datasets in Power BI by using Power BI datasets with live connection method. We want that dataset to be connected to Azure SQL database. Is there any way to do so ? Please share a link.

Comment: Shruti, are you trying to get PowerBi dataset data into Azure sql DB or do you want to join PowerBI dataset with an existing Azure SQL DB ?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot combine live data with any other imported data**. Power BI does not permit that. If you are using a live connection, you cannot use any other data source in that report. For more details check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-ssas-multidimensional

You get the below error.

[image]

**Alternately....**

If you plan to use a **local source as dataset** and **Azure SQL DB**, that is possible as below.

Example Source connections:

[image]

Use **Merge Queries** in **Power Query editor**

[image]

Join tables based on columns and manage relationships as per your need.

[image]

Resulting table having data from both sources.

[image]